# Не работает websocket с nginx

Tags: nginx, websocket

На сервере запущен Ratchet, слушающий порт 8080. Стоит apache, в конфиге которого добавлено:

ProxyPass /wss2/ ws://мой-сайт.com:8080/

Со стороны клиента подключаюсь по адресу wss://мой-сайт.com/wss2/. Всё работает.
Ставлю nginx. В его конфиг добавляю:

```
upstream websocket {
        server 127.0.0.1:8080;
    }

server {
    ...
    listen 443 ssl;
    location /wss2/ {
        proxy_pass http://websocket;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

При подключении по wss://мой-сайт.com/wss2/ получаю 503 Service Unavailable. Пробовал вместо 127.0.0.1 подставлять мой-сайт.com, убирал совсем секцию upstream, при подключении указывал номер порта. Результат один и тот же.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Конфиг рабочий. Версия nginx > 1.3.13 ? после правки конфига nginx перезагружали?

Comment: Попробуйте в proxy_pass поставить слеш в конце

Comment: @total конфиг рабочий, версия 1.12.2, перезагружал

Comment: @AlexeyTen попробовал, не помогло

Comment: Скопипастил конфиг, проверил, у меня работает. 1) сделайте `sudo nginx -t`, должно выводить что все в порядке. 2) Включите лог ошибок и посмотрите что в него падает, выхлоп сюда. 3) давайте искать ошибку на стыке nginx => 8080. Точно ваш бек-сервер работает по адресу `ws://мой-сайт.com:8080/wss2/` - обратите внимание, что именно `/wss2/`, а не `/`?

Comment: @TotalPusher сменил порт, всё заработало. Спасибо!